# Rendering multiple react component from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a react component, Let's say  `component_1`.
And, my array is of the form, let's say, `array_list  =`[{},{},{},{}].

I'm trying to render this component inside my another component, component_2, like so:

```
import component_1 from 'component_1'
import array_list from 'array_list'

class component_2 extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    const {renderMenu} = this.props
    var contentData = [];
    array_list.forEach(function(item, index, array){
          contentData.push(<component_1 {...item} />);
    });
    return(
        <div>
        <div className="ui four column centered grid">
           {contentData}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default component_2
```

while, it generally works with other HTML elements. Here it throws an error:

```
React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `OnBoardingContentElement`
```

Can render an array of react component's this way? If not, then is there any circumvent approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your import statement is working? Also look into array.map, it is perfect for turning an array of object data into an array of components.

Comment: Which import statement? I'm assuming you are talking about the array_list, It yes, then answer is no, it wont work. It's just a sudo-code. I'm creating the array_list inside the function.

Comment: No, your component import. If createElement is complaining about null then it sounds like your component isn't being imported properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow up to @John's answer.

I ran into this exact problem last night. Here's what I was doing:

```
// MyComponent.js

export const MyComponent = (<h1>Hello, world</h1>);

// index.js

import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

React.render((<MyComponent />), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Can you see the error? It's kind of subtle.

The problem is that the `MyComponent.js` is NOT exporting a React component. It's exporting a React element that's already instantiated.

@John is suggesting that this might be what you're doing. The best way to correct it is the ensure that `MyComponent.js` is actually exporting a component:

```
// MyComponent.js

export const MyComponent = () => (<h1>Hello, world</h1>);
```